# Light HTTP server to upload,browse and execute files

Tags: server, remote

Since I don't usually have physical access to the Pi, and since I don't always operate in linux machines (so I have no `ssh` by default), then I'm wondering if there exists a basic http tool to just 1)browse, 2)upload and 3)execute files.

The ideal server should be executed with something like:

```
 server-http --user pi --pass three.1415 --p 8080 --folder ~/media --execute xdg-open
```

This should tell to the server:

- to listen to the port 8080 with Basic access authentication
- to serve  the folder `~/media`, to serve its file, and let the user upload a file
- to let the user execute the files. This means that when a file is clicked then the server executes `xdg-open filename`.

I'm guessing such a tool does not exist yet. However, I know multiple languages and I'm ready to develop the missing components if I find a tool which is close to these specs.

The ideal server should be minimal and in C to be as light as possible.

Thanks!

Comment: While not explicitly off-topic here, as you are asking to have software that would run fine on a Pi, this might get a better response and better answers over on [so] as that is a **Programming-Specific** stack exchange.

Comment: The 'execute file' bit is a bad idea. Consider finding a portable ssh client instead - I believe there is a Java applet version which can run on any host with Java support in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made my own little webserver: https://github.com/spocchio/hbue.py

I can just run

```
python hbue.py --ssl my_certificate.pem --execute xdg-open --credentials 'user:password' --folder /home/pi/data -listen 'localhost:4443'
```

Answer (score 3):

What Ive done is that I installed apache, created a simple PHP file that has buttons and in the back it make `exec` calls to the scripts.
For remote file access on windows I recommend winSCP that allows you to online edit the files using your favorite editor (you can do similar with filezilla but is a bit more tedious).

if you don't want to change the PHP with every new script you add it is fairly easy to create a php file that scans the folder and create html 'buttons' for each script it finds.

If you need directions on that don't hesitate asking.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion: I think `apache` is a bit huge for this purpose. Or do you think it would be lighter than e.g. a `web.py` server?

Comment: I dont know what you wanna do but I have apache on the pi running at the same time than an XBMC (xBian) and I can surf my pages while my gf watch series from the internet and no one notices. I think the trade-off easiness/CPU usage is clearly won by apache :)

Answer (score 1):

I have used Windows Remote Desktop Connection to access the Pi - I get the LXDE screen on my PC, and can use the Pi just as if I was using its own screen and keyboard.

I also use "Map network drive" in Windows Explorer to have the Pi appear as a disk drive on the PC - I've used an editor on the PC to edit files on the Pi, and can easily transfer files between the Pi and the PC.

I also use Putty to provide an SSH connection to the Pi to access the Pi command line.